# Comparing in Prometheus two metrics from different exporters when one of them is null

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am using Prometheus to monitor a list of servers.

One of the rules I have compares two metrics from different metrics exporters. It does something like this:

```
exporter1_metric() > exporter2_metric()
```

When the first metric returns null, the comparison does not work since null != number.

In my specific case, I compare the number of processes running with "OPP" in the "groupname" tag with a value from a database. These two metrics have in common the tags "client", "manager" and "link".

```
namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs{groupname=~".*OPP.*"}
< on (client, manager, link) group_right ()
oracledb_ebs_concurrent_queues_target_processes{concurrent_queue_name=~".*OPP.*"}
```

This method works perfectly when there are one or more of those processes running (first metric), but whenever the number of processes is "0", the metric "namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs" does not return any value, so I cannot compare it with the database value.

Using "on() vector(0)" to detect when the value is null and convert it to a "0" does not work either, since the "vector(0)" does not store the "client", "manager" and "link" tags, which are needed for comparison:

```
... namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs{groupname=~".*OPP.*"} or on() vector(0) > ...
```

Is there any way to trigger the rule when the left side of the comparison is null? If the right side is null, I don't want to trigger the alert, as it means the alert is not applicable to that specific instance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have two alerts: current one and alert if `namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs` is absent?

Comment: `namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs` should only trigger when is null AND if there is a value returned by `oracledb_ebs_concurrent_queues_target_processes` with that three labels (client, manager, link).`

There are some instances where `namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs` shouldn't return any value because there shouldn't be any of these processes. Thats why I need to compare it to the value of the other metric.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep current comparison rule add another alerting rule, than will check absence of `namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs`.

It's expression would be like this:

```
oracledb_ebs_concurrent_queues_target_processes{concurrent_queue_name=~".*OPP.*"} unless on (client, manager, link) namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs{groupname=~".*OPP.*"}
```

It returns values of `oracledb_ebs_concurrent_queues_target_processes` unless `namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs` with corresponding set of labels (client, manager, link) exists.